# How do I get the header properly alinged with navmenu in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please excuse the sloppiness and unused attributes in this markup. It's due to my constant mistakes and messing around. I'll fix it when I'm towards the end of development.

For some reason, the header in this markup is only correctly centered in firefox. But with the use of safari and chrome it's slightly to the right and I presume it's the same for other browser aswell.

I did use , padding-left , but then again, that only works in firefox. Is there a universal way where it stays centered in all browsers?

I also noticed that when I attached the link to the logo, the whole header is shown to be clickable, I just want the black box to be.

And is there a way where the website stays the same size in all browsers?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />


<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 0px; width: center; margin: auto }
.slideshow img { padding-top: 40px;}
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var controller = $.superscrollorama({
            triggerAtCenter: false,
            playoutAnimations: true,
        });
    });
    </script>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/jquery/script.js"></script>



<div id="logo">
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/Revealedclothing/index.htm">
<h1>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="headerContainer">
        </div>
       </div>

    <img src="http://oi40.tinypic.com/iz1ag0.png" width="250" height="134" style=" margin: 0 auto; width: center; padding-top:20px;  padding-left:128px;
    padding-left:258px;"></h1>


<style></style>

<style>h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: ;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: center;
    padding-left:515px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
}
</style>

</div>

<style>
<!-- Use this for future backgrounds (optimum resolution: 1448 - 697) --> 
body
{
background:url("");
background-size:0px 0px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-top:0px;

<!-- Use this for future backgrounds (optimum resolution: 1448 - 697) -->


}
<!--
 a:hover{color:none;}
-->
    .navLink {
    color: #000000;    
    text-decoration: none !important;}
ul
{
list-style-type:none;
font-size: 85%;
font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: regular;}
{
display:inline;
}
</style>

<head>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>UNKOWN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="star-light/star-light.css" media="all">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#nav-one li").hover(
                function(){ $("ul", this).fadeIn("slow"); }, 
                function() { } 
            );
        if (document.all) {
                $("#nav-one li").hoverClass ("sfHover");
            }
      });

        $.fn.hoverClass = function(c) {
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).hover( 
                    function() { $(this).addClass(c);  },
                    function() { $(this).removeClass(c); }
                );
            });
        };    
    </script>



<style type="text/css">

/* Navigation */
.nav, .nav ul { 
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 center;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100;
    img
opacity:0.4;
filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.nav {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
  z-index: 100;
  position: relative;
  padding-left:110px;
}
.nav li {
  border-left: 0px solid #000;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.nav li a, .nav li a:link, .nav li a:active, .nav li a:visited {
  font: 1em/25px 'Ubuntu Condensed', sans-serif;
  background:   #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 14px;
  text-transform: Uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;  

}
#nav-one li:hover a, 
#nav-one li.sfHover a {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
}
#nav-one li:hover ul a, 
#nav-one li.sfHover ul a {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;   
}
#nav-one li:hover ul a:hover, 
#nav-one li.sfHover ul a:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;  
}

.nav ul {
  background:   #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 0px solid #000;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  left: -1px;
}
.nav li:hover ul,
.nav li.sfHover ul {
  top: 25px;
}
.nav ul li {
  border: 0;
  float: none;
}
.nav ul a {
  border: 0px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 80px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav ul a:hover {
  background:   #FFFFFF;
  color: #000;
}

.nav ul {
    width: 25.5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

ul {
    width: 25.5%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
</style>


        <script>/*
jQuery Waypoints - v1.1.7
Copyright (c) 2011-2012 Caleb Troughton
Dual licensed under the MIT license and GPL license.
https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/blob/master/MIT-license.txt
https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/blob/master/GPL-license.txt
*/
(function($,k,m,i,d){var e=$(i),g="waypoint.reached",b=function(o,n){o.element.trigger(g,n);if(o.options.triggerOnce){o.element[k]("destroy")}},h=function(p,o){if(!o){return -1}var n=o.waypoints.length-1;while(n>=0&&o.waypoints[n].element[0]!==p[0]){n-=1}return n},f=[],l=function(n){$.extend(this,{element:$(n),oldScroll:0,waypoints:[],didScroll:false,didResize:false,doScroll:$.proxy(function(){var q=this.element.scrollTop(),p=q>this.oldScroll,s=this,r=$.grep(this.waypoints,function(u,t){return p?(u.offset>s.oldScroll&&u.offset<=q):(u.offset<=s.oldScroll&&u.offset>q)}),o=r.length;if(!this.oldScroll||!q){$[m]("refresh")}this.oldScroll=q;if(!o){return}if(!p){r.reverse()}$.each(r,function(u,t){if(t.options.continuous||u===o-1){b(t,[p?"down":"up"])}})},this)});$(n).bind("scroll.waypoints",$.proxy(function(){if(!this.didScroll){this.didScroll=true;i.setTimeout($.proxy(function(){this.doScroll();this.didScroll=false},this),$[m].settings.scrollThrottle)}},this)).bind("resize.waypoints",$.proxy(function(){if(!this.didResize){this.didResize=true;i.setTimeout($.proxy(function(){$[m]("refresh");this.didResize=false},this),$[m].settings.resizeThrottle)}},this));e.load($.proxy(function(){this.doScroll()},this))},j=function(n){var o=null;$.each(f,function(p,q){if(q.element[0]===n){o=q;return false}});return o},c={init:function(o,n){this.each(function(){var u=$.fn[k].defaults.context,q,t=$(this);if(n&&n.context){u=n.context}if(!$.isWindow(u)){u=t.closest(u)[0]}q=j(u);if(!q){q=new l(u);f.push(q)}var p=h(t,q),s=p<0?$.fn[k].defaults:q.waypoints[p].options,r=$.extend({},s,n);r.offset=r.offset==="bottom-in-view"?function(){var v=$.isWindow(u)?$[m]("viewportHeight"):$(u).height();return v-$(this).outerHeight()}:r.offset;if(p<0){q.waypoints.push({element:t,offset:null,options:r})}else{q.waypoints[p].options=r}if(o){t.bind(g,o)}if(n&&n.handler){t.bind(g,n.handler)}});$[m]("refresh");return this},remove:function(){return this.each(function(o,p){var n=$(p);$.each(f,function(r,s){var q=h(n,s);if(q>=0){s.waypoints.splice(q,1);if(!s.waypoints.length){s.element.unbind("scroll.waypoints resize.waypoints");f.splice(r,1)}}})})},destroy:function(){return this.unbind(g)[k]("remove")}},a={refresh:function(){$.each(f,function(r,s){var q=$.isWindow(s.element[0]),n=q?0:s.element.offset().top,p=q?$[m]("viewportHeight"):s.element.height(),o=q?0:s.element.scrollTop();$.each(s.waypoints,function(u,x){if(!x){return}var t=x.options.offset,w=x.offset;if(typeof x.options.offset==="function"){t=x.options.offset.apply(x.element)}else{if(typeof x.options.offset==="string"){var v=parseFloat(x.options.offset);t=x.options.offset.indexOf("%")?Math.ceil(p*(v/100)):v}}x.offset=x.element.offset().top-n+o-t;if(x.options.onlyOnScroll){return}if(w!==null&&s.oldScroll>w&&s.oldScroll<=x.offset){b(x,["up"])}else{if(w!==null&&s.oldScroll<w&&s.oldScroll>=x.offset){b(x,["down"])}else{if(!w&&s.element.scrollTop()>x.offset){b(x,["down"])}}}});s.waypoints.sort(function(u,t){return u.offset-t.offset})})},viewportHeight:function(){return(i.innerHeight?i.innerHeight:e.height())},aggregate:function(){var n=$();$.each(f,function(o,p){$.each(p.waypoints,function(q,r){n=n.add(r.element)})});return n}};$.fn[k]=function(n){if(c[n]){return c[n].apply(this,Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1))}else{if(typeof n==="function"||!n){return c.init.apply(this,arguments)}else{if(typeof n==="object"){return c.init.apply(this,[null,n])}else{$.error("Method "+n+" does not exist on jQuery "+k)}}}};$.fn[k].defaults={continuous:true,offset:0,triggerOnce:false,context:i};$[m]=function(n){if(a[n]){return a[n].apply(this)}else{return a.aggregate()}};$[m].settings={resizeThrottle:200,scrollThrottle:100};e.load(function(){$[m]("refresh")})})(jQuery,"waypoint","waypoints",window);</script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft', 
    speed:  270 // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>







</head>



</head>
<body>




<hr style="border: none; height: 1px; color: #C0C0C0; background: #C0C0C0;"/>

<tr>  
<td><ul id="nav-one" class="nav">


            <li>

                <a href="#item1">MEN'S</a>
                <ul style="opacity: 0.9999; display: block;">
                    <li><a href="#item1.2">New Arrivals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8020/MEN%27S-/INDEX.HTM">Tops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item1.2">Bottoms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item1.3">Outerwear</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item1.4">Shoes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item2">WOMEN'S</a>
                <ul style="opacity: 0.9999; display: none;">
                    <li><a href="#item1.2">New Arrivals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item1.1">Tops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item1.2">Bottoms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item1.3">Outerwear</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item1.4">Bags</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item3">COLLECTION</a>
                <ul style="opacity: 0.9999; display: block;">
                    <li><a href="#item3.1">SHOWCASE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item3.2">MEN'S</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#item3.2">WOMEN'S</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#item4">BAGS</a>
                <ul style="opacity: 0.9999; display: block;">

                </ul>
<li>
                <a href="#item4">BLOG</a>
                <ul style="opacity: 0.9999; display: block;">
            </ul>




</ul>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><div class="slideshow" style="position: top;">
        <img src="http://oi40.tinypic.com/iz1ag0.png" width="1448" height="697" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 697px;">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="1448" height="697" style="position: center; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 697px;">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="1448" height="697" style="position: center; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 697px;">
        <img src="http://oi40.tinypic.com/iz1ag0.png" width="1448" height="697" style="position: center; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 5; opacity: 0; width: 100%; height: 697px;">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach5.jpg" width="1448" height="697" style="position: center; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block; z-index: 6; opacity: 1;width: 100%; height: 697px;">
    </div></td>
</tr>

</body>




</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/29Xc2/

Comment: `width: center`? I'm not reading any further.

Comment: Was that an insult or an actual question? Maybe you can't read my first sentence? I'm sorry not everyone is Bill Gates Sir.

Comment: Sarcasm aside, different browsers respond differently to errors, so if you have errors, you will get different results. Correct the errors and the differences will disappear.